# Why does DataPager need Pre-Render event to work??

Tags: asp.net, listview, paging, datapager

Having to use pre render is causing me problems.. It would be great if I did not need it.. The problem is I have the list in a user control and when I goto the next 'page' I databind.. but then the datapager prerenders.. which also does a batabind.. so it runs twice..

If I remove the prerender .. then clicking next 'page' does nothing..

Any idea?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetSearchResults();
}

//protected void dpMembers_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{
//    GetSearchResults();
//}

public void GetSearchResults()
{
    List<Person> listPerson = new List<Person>();
    string strServer = "localhost";
    string strAppPath = Server.MapPath("/");
    PersonBusiness pb = new PersonBusiness(new PersonRepository());
    listPerson = pb.GetAllPersons(strServer, strAppPath);
    lvPersons.DataSource = listPerson;
    lvPersons.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I don't think the Pre_Render is the right place to be updating data used by a control. What's the rest of your code related to paging look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your Page load to

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    GetSearchResults();
  }
}

your prerender seems ok.

Comment: Yeah, the IsPostBack is the solution.

Comment: yeah. .thats one way.. im stupid and realized I was doing things the hard way.. I was binding the control from the page.. when that was not even needed.. just the user control being on the page was good enough.. no need to BIND it from the outside.